# Continuity upgrade for nonlinear maps

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

Let $E,F,G$ be topological vector spaces such that $F\subset G$ with continuous embedding.

By *continuity upgrade* I mean the following phenomenon: In some circumstances a continuous linear map $f:E\rightarrow G$ with $f(E)\subset F$ is automatically continuous as map $f:E\rightarrow F$. This is true e.g. if all involved spaces are Fréchet (and then follows from the closed range theorem).

I am interested in nonlinear versions of this phenomenon. One example for this is if  $f$ is a quadratic form, i.e. $f(x)=b(x,x)$ for a bilinear map $b:E\times E\rightarrow G$. In this case one can use the linear result for $b(x,\cdot)$ and $b(\cdot,y)$ to conclude that $b:E\times E \rightarrow F$ is separately continuous in each variable and (at least in the Fréchet setting) this implies joint continuity and thus continuity of $f:E\rightarrow F$.

**Question**. Let $f:E\rightarrow G$ be a continuous (possibly non-linear) map with $f(E)\subset F$. Which conditions on $f$ (e.g. growth conditions, algebraic conditions) and on the involved spaces ensure that $f$ is continuous as map $f:E\rightarrow F$?